# Can a field of a Java class be of multiple types without using generics?

Tags: java, types, sonarqube, field

I have a class, which's instances will be serialized. Thus the class implements `Serializable`. The class has a field of type `List`, which must be `Serializable` as well of course. Imagine the class looking something like this:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class Report implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 12345L;

    private List<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Now I know that `ArrayList` is `Serializable`, but I'd rather declare my field to be of some interface type.

The issue comes when our SonarQube analyzes the code. It complains, that the field `records` should be of some `Serializable` type as well and SonarQube is right.

But due to the fact that the field is an implementation detail (a private member), I don't want to use generics on the class.

And here comes my question:
With the self applied constraints to declare the field of some interface type and not use generics, is it possible to declare the field to be of multiple (interface) types?

FYI: I know one can cast to multiple types, but that's something entirely different.

```
Object o = (List<Serializable> & Serializable) new ArrayList<Serializable>();
```

The above is perfectly legal although unnecessary.

Comment: You could declare your field `transient`though, if it isn't important if the field gets serialized or not.

Comment: @Joshua Good point but no, the field needs to be transferred as well. :)

Comment: Why do you say SonarQube is right?  I'd see it as just being nitpicky.

Comment: @LouisWasserman One could say that to a lot of rules. Imho the type of a variable declaration is also a message to fellow developers who maintain the code. Something like: "Hey there, whenever you change to value of this variable, make sure it complies with the requirements." If the type of the field is `List`, one could assign an instance, which is not `Serializable` and no compiler can detect the error. Now one could ask: Is the compiler required to detect such an error? Not unless one specifies the field to be `Serializable`, which one cannot do by sticking to interfaces only so it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short and disillusioning answer is: No, a field cannot be of multiple types simultaneously without using generics or custom classes.

What I was looking for was a way to declare a field - actually any kind of variable - to be of an intersection type.
Whilst [intersection types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/IntersectionType.html) exist in Java since the introduction of generics in Java 6, lambda support in Java 8 needed and brought us intersection casts. Still, intersection types for variables have yet to be implemented. Let's hope for the best.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your field is `private` anyway, so whether it's a `List` or an `ArrayList` does not really matter. You could just make the field a serializable `ArrayList` and use `List` in the getter.

```
public class Report implements Serializable {

    private ArrayList<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();

    ...

    public List<Record> getRecords() {
        return this.records;
    }
}
```

(While this does not answer the question of whether a field can have multiple types, it might be a solution to your actual problem.)

Comment: hehe, then SonarQube will criticize that you use an implementation over an interface. Ran into this trap way too ofter.

Comment: As @Joshua mentioned, then I get another warning or hint from SonarQube. So there's no win in changing the declaration type. Fwiw: I agree that this solves the problem of ensuring some kind of declared serializability and due to the fact that it's an implementation detail, I wouldn't care. Regarding this, I think the default SonarQube rules are a bit too strict. Maybe I'll use the explicit type and use `//NOSONAR` to ignore the warning.

Comment: @Brian I am as anxious for seeing a better solution to this as you are, but until then, deactivating this check for this element (or just ignoring the warning) might be the best way.